# Why a Violation of Unique Constraint on date time column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, unique-constraint

I have a table with an `ID` and a `DateTime` column

This table has a unique key on `ID` and `DateTime`

`DateTime` is nullable

The `ID` is not a PK

I enter a row

```
ID  DATETIME
1   NULL
```

Then later I set a value for date time

```
ID  DATEIME
1   2014-07-21 13:34:098
```

Then I want to add a new row to make something like this

```
ID  DATETIME 
1   2014-07-21 13:34:098 
1   NULL
```

For example the row ID 1 with a NULL datetime is the current active row or something.

Now when, for example, I go to invalidate this current active row, and insert a different time stamp for active row with ID 1

```
ID  DATETIME
1   2014-07-21 18:20:51.510
1   2014-07-21 18:28:55.710
```

I get a UK violation. Doesn't seem to make sense.

The time stamp is not duplicate.

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint UK_MyTable. Cannot insert duplicate key in object Schema.MyTable. The duplicate key value is (222333, Jul 21 2014  8:26PM)
>
> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint UK_MyTable. Cannot insert duplicate key in object Schema.MyTable. The duplicate key value is (1, Jul 21 2014  8:28PM)

Can anyone shed any light as to why this happening?

Here is he Unique Constraint

```
ALTER TABLE [Scheme].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [UK_MyTable] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [DateTime] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Then just update the DateTime field before I insert a new row

```
update Scheme.MyTable set DateTime = getutcdate() where ID= 1
```

Comment: can you paste the sql you are running to insert data?

Comment: The ID might not be a PK, but there is clearly another UNIQUE constraint active here. Inspect the creation statement for this table. What RDBMS is this? Looks like it is likely MySQL or PostgreSQL

Comment: Can you please also past how you are defining unique constraint ?

Comment: sounds like you are inserting instead of updating???

Comment: Can you share the SQL that's you're using? Perhaps create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a composite unique key on both those fields and not 2 unique keys (one on EACH field)?

Comment: Please edit you question and show:  the layout of the table and the definitions of the constraints/indexes.  Also, tag your question with the appropriate database tag.

Comment: Are there any triggers defined on this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the query you're running, then of course you're getting an error:

```
update Scheme.MyTable set DateTime = getutcdate() where ID= 1
```

There's nothing there to tell the server that you only wanted to affect the row with a `NULL` `DateTime` so it affects both rows and tries to give them the same value.

Maybe:

```
update Scheme.MyTable set DateTime = getutcdate()
  where ID= 1 and DateTime is NULL
```

Comment: argh, le sigh. i didn't see it :(

Answer (score 3):

when you run this query

```
update Scheme.MyTable set DateTime = getutcdate() where ID= 1
```

it will make 2 row with the same key

both `ID` 1 will have the **SAME** `DateTime`

so yes, this will violate unique constraint